# how to use the variable from if isset $_POST output?

Tags: php, if-statement

How do I use the value of variable $dd i.e 10 or 100000 outside the if condition?
I want to show that status(available/not available) and the $dd value in separate locations.

**ajax success**

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#uname_response").html(response);
}
```

```
 if(isset($_POST['applied_promocode'])){
         $applied_promocode = $_POST['applied_promocode'];

         $dd = 0;
      
         // Check applied_promocode
         $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) as cntUser FROM coupon WHERE applied_promocode=:applied_promocode");
         $stmt->bindValue(':applied_promocode', $applied_promocode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->execute(); 
         $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

         //Availability message
         if($count > 0){
            $response = "<span style='color: red;'>Not Available.</span>";
            $dd = 10;
         } else {
            $response = "<span style='color: green;'>Available.</span>";
            $dd = 100000;
         }

         echo $dd;
         echo $response;
         exit;
      }

      $discount_price = $dd * 100;
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Do you get errors? Unexpected behaviour? Do you not know how to transfer these values back to AJAX?

Comment: I'm not getting errors but unable to use the value of $dd in $discount_price and the value of both $dd and $response shows in a single div with single id whereas i want to show it in different divs

Comment: Unable to how? What does that mean?

Comment: First of all, you cannot return/echo two values server side. If you want to return multiple values, switch to JSON data, thereby allowing you to return arrays or objects.

Comment: Besides the obvious `exit;` that will terminate the script and make your code never reach `$discount_price = $dd * 100;`.

Comment: As for _"shows in a single div with single id"_ - that's exactly what you're doing in `$("#uname_response").html(response);`. You don't even attempt to place them in separate HTML containers. It cannot know on its own what you meant to place where.

Comment: @El_Vanja I want to show the available status in a separate div and the dd price in another div.

Comment: Then you need to send your data in a structured way as @asprin already suggested so that you can separate it easily.

Comment: How do you do that? @asprin

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to send back data in JSON format if you want to be able to pass complex data (i.e. non-string value). The way to do that would be as follows:

### Untested code

```
if($count > 0){
    $response = "Not Available";
    $dd = 10;
 } else {
    $response = "Available";
    $dd = 100000;
 }

 $discount_price = $dd * 100;
 
 $json_data = array('response'=>$response, 'dd' => $discount_price);
 
 echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Then on the client side, you can use something like this:

```
success: function (response) {
    var json_data = JSON.parse(response);
    var color = "red";
    if(json_data.response == 'Available')
    {
        color = "green";
    }
    
    var html = "<span style='color: "+color+";'>"+json_data.response+".</span><p>"Discounted price = "+json_data.dd+"</p>";
    $("#uname_response").html(html);
}
```

Or if you do not like concatenation, use the traditional approach to manipulate the DOM

```
success: function (response) {
    var json_data = JSON.parse(response);
    
    if(json_data && json_data.response)
    {
        var color = "red";
        if(json_data.response == 'Available')
        {
            color = "green";
        }
        
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.style.color = color;
        span.innerHTML = json_data.response;
        
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = "Discounted price is "+json_data.dd;
        
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(span);
        div.appendChild(p);     
        
        $("#uname_response").html(div);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Invalid data returned from server");
    }
}
```

Comment: VM185:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 36
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (main.js:273)

Comment: Shows error in this line var json_data = JSON.parse(response);

Comment: What is the response that you're getting? Check the network tab on the browser console

Comment: {"response":"Not Available","dd":10}{"cart_details":"\r\n..........and it goes on

Comment: Why is `cart_details` coming from? I think you added something more to your server side code